# Math on rows in column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, series

I am trying to find code that will allow me to subtract a value in the last row of a column from the value in the second to last value in the same column.  Here's what I have tried.

```
df_stock2['eps_median_est'][-1] - df_stock2['eps_median_est'][-2]
```

> error is :  TypeError: an integer is required

my datatype is

```
eps_median_est, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) (or `iloc`) for fast scalar access by integer position:

```
res = df_stock2['eps_median_est'].iat[-1] - df_stock2['eps_median_est'].iat[-2]
```

Alternatively, using NumPy:

```
A = df_stock2['eps_median_est'].values
res = A[-1] - A[-2]
```

Comment: Excellent, feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (green tick on left) if this helped.